# Use local variable to query scalar valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns a list of cat codes:

```
SELECT  Catcode From tbluserslogin
join tblUserRoleMapping
    on tblUserRoleMapping.UserID = tblUsersLogin.LoginUserID
join tblCats
    on UserName = CatCode
where RoleID = 87
```

This returns:

[image]

```
SELECT dbo.GetCatManager('', 1) <--this is my function
```

that returns a manager code based on the input catcode

How do I create a variable that I could use in my function from the list of cat codes?

I was looking at local variables but was having trouble with the syntax.

Does something like work:

```
@CatCode = CatCode
```

So that my function would look like this:

```
SELECT dbo.GetAgentManager('@CatCode', 1)
```

Is this possible and how would i do it?

Comment: Would be better if you could get rid of the scalar function. They are notoriously poor from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're after is

```
SELECT  dbo.GetAgentManager(Catcode,1) AS ManagerCode 
From tbluserslogin
join tblUserRoleMapping
    on tblUserRoleMapping.UserID = tblUsersLogin.LoginUserID
join tblCats
    on UserName = CatCode
where RoleID = 87
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly  use your function:

```
SELECT  Catcode, dbo.GetAgentManager(Catcode, 1) as Manager From tbluserslogin
join tblUserRoleMapping
    on tblUserRoleMapping.UserID = tblUsersLogin.LoginUserID
join tblCats
    on UserName = CatCode
where RoleID = 87
```